# Swift delegate responseToSelector Bad_Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, swift

I'm trying integrating ASIHTTPRequest to Swift project
this is my class

```
class DataCenter : NSObject, ASIHTTPRequestDelegate{
    // ...
    func requestAllPrice() {
        var url = NSURL.URLWithString("www.baidu.com");
        var req = ASIHTTPRequest.requestWithURL(url) as ASIHTTPRequest
        req.delegate = self
        req.didFinishSelector = Selector("priceRequestDone")
        self.queue.addOperation(req);

    }

    func priceRequestDone( request : ASIHTTPRequest ){
        var response = request.responseString()
        println(response)
    }

    func requestFailed( req : ASIHTTPRequest ){
        println(req.error)
    }
}
```

but I got error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at ASIHTTPRequest.m :

```
- (void)requestStarted{
    if ([self error] || [self mainRequest]) {
        return;
    }
    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:didStartSelector]) {
        [delegate performSelector:didStartSelector withObject:self];
    }
    #if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
    if(startedBlock){
        startedBlock();
    }
    #endif
    if (queue && [queue respondsToSelector:@selector(requestStarted:)]) {
        [queue performSelector:@selector(requestStarted:) withObject:self];
    }
}
```

at line 'if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:didStartSelector]) {'

this is the definition of the ASIHTTPRequestDelegate:

```
@class ASIHTTPRequest;
@protocol ASIHTTPRequestDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

// These are the default delegate methods for request status
// You can use different ones by setting didStartSelector / didFinishSelector / didFailSelector
- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders;
- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request willRedirectToURL:(NSURL *)newURL;
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestRedirected:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
...
@end
```

I try assign a Selector to self.didStartSelector, it report bad access at a compilation code.
Help me pls!

Comment: ASI? I thought that died years ago.

Comment: do you know some lib newer for netoperation?

Comment: AFNetworking.  http://nshipster.com/afnetworking-2/

Comment: Why do you need a library to do this? Apple provide all the APIs you need to do it natively.

Comment: `[delegate respondsToSelector:didStartSelector]` must be `[delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didStartSelector:)]` and `[delegate performSelector:didStartSelector withObject:self];` must be `[delegate performSelector:@selector(didStartSelector:) withObject:self];` instead. I should create an answer for that...

Comment: Are you sure that your object is being kept alive long enough to receive this message? Like most classes, ASIHTTPRequest does not retain its delegate, so you will get this error if the delegate goes away before the request does.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm now going to discard ASIHTTP after dicussing with my co, it is so old.

Comment: @Chuck, it is alive always, it seems to be a bug of swift with oc. It works fine after I use the AFNetworking, and thanks Brandon